# Randomly chose an action (definition) with random.choice()

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Code doesn't work like it should.  It is just a small thing i would like to learn as a new coder:

```
import turtle
import random
me=turtle.Turtle()
def up_right(): 
   me.right(90)
   me.forward(100)

def down_right():
me.right(90)
me.forward(100)
choose = (up_right(), down_right)
random.choice(chose)
```

It should pick one and do it but it picks them both.
I've tried `random.sample` and `random.choice` but cant get them to work.

Comment: What precisely doesn't work correctly?

Comment: Your code will throw a name error on `chose`. If that is a simple typo, it still won't do what you want because it doesn't reduce the sample in place. `choose =random.choice(choose)` will reduce it to a single value

Comment: It looks like you're not doing anything with the one you select randomly.  Also, in `(up_right(), down_right)`, you're calling `up_right`, which will execute that function immediately, without waiting for the random selection.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the typo of `choose`... My suggestion is that after you create a tuple of functions and choose the function using `random.choice()`, you should make a call to the function chosen by the `random.choice()`.

```
# Notice I removed the () after up_right so it doesn't make the function call on this line
choose = (up_right, down_right) 
# random.choice will return one of the two, and then the () will call whatever function was chosen
random.choice(choose)()
```

Answer (score 0):

I see three issues with your code.  The first two folks have pointed out already, the `choose` vs `chose` typo and leaving the parens () on `upright` when refering to it as a function `(up_right(), down_right)`.

The third is that `up_right` and `down_right` both implement the same motion, so even if the rest of your code worked, you wouldn't see any difference!  Below's a rewrite that fixes this issue:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import choice

def up_right(turtle):
    turtle.setheading(90)
    turtle.forward(100)

def down_right(turtle):
    turtle.setheading(270)
    turtle.forward(100)

choices = [up_right, down_right]

screen = Screen()

me = Turtle('turtle')

choice(choices)(me)

screen.mainloop()
```

Run it several times and you'll see sometimes the turtle heads up the screen, sometimes it heads down.